# How do I remove the install "Sample Data" dialogue box and permanently disable this option?

Tags: joomla-3.x

How do I remove the install "Sample Data" dialogue box in the Joomla control panel and permanently disable this option?

I'm using Joomla! 3.8.1

[image: Sample Data Dialogue Box]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**"Sample Data" Module vs. "Sample Data - Blog" Plugin**

The "Sample Data" window is a module (the box that shows the information) and "Sample Data - Blog" is a plugin, shown in the "Sample Data" module.

**STEP 1: Hiding the Sample Data Module in the Admin Panel**

This module takes up prime real-state in the Joomla admin panel and there's no point showing it if you are never going to use it (e.g. your site is already live or in production).

So just go to Extensions -> Modules, switch dropdown to "administrator" instead of "site", search for Sample Data unpublish this module.

This hides the module from view in the administrator panel, and the "Sample Data module resides as 'Trashed,' but it is not permanently deleted as modules" can be restored from 'unpublished' status.

**STEP 2: Unistalling the Sample Data - Blog plugin**

In the case of the Sample Data - Blog plugin, the issue is that'Trash' or 'Uninstall' plugins in the Plugin Manager.

To 'uninstall' the Sample Data - Blog plugin go to Extensions -> Manage -> --> Manage(yes again), and then'll you have an 'uninstall' option. Search for 'Sample Data - Blog,' uninstall, and it's permanently gone from your Joomla site.